# Flutter to Set Color from Database value Asynchronously

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, async-await, widget

I have a scenario like this.

1. http call will get data from server as a List
2. I have to loop through the list to show a Container with particular color
3. Color is selected based on a database value (sqlite)
4. When trying to set color from an async function it wont work

   ```
   Future<Color> _getColor(id) async {
       Color myColor;
       myColor = await helper.queryColor(id);
       return myColor;
    }



   for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
       Container(
       color: await _getColor(list.id);
        )}
   ```

But it showing an error **The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color'.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could achieve what i want with the help of **Future Builder**

```
 child: FutureBuilder<Color>(
      future: _getColor(message[i].sId), //This function return color from Sqlite DB Asynchronously
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Color> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Card(color: snapshot.data);
        }
        else
         return CupertinoActivityIndicator();
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

As your _getColor is defined as a Future/Async function then you need to call it as an await-able function.

`for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
    Container(
    color: await _getColor(list.id),
  );
  }`

Comment: The argument type 'Future<Color>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color'.